# error while running a simple cursor in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error

I am trying to write a simple cursor and open, fetch the values and close. Below is my cursor code.

```
DECLARE
  id    cur.sid%TYPE;
  s_num cur.serial#%TYPE;
  CURSOR cur IS
    SELECT sid, serial#
    FROM v$session WHERE username = 'ABC';
BEGIN
  OPEN cur;

  LOOP
    FETCH c cur INTO id, s_num;
    dbms_output.put_line(id || ' ' || s_num);
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur;
END;
/
```

While running this I am seeing the following error message:

```
FETCH c cur INTO id, s_num;
        *
ERROR at line 9:
ORA-06550: line 9, column 9:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CUR" when expecting one of the following:
. into bulk
The symbol "." was substituted for "CUR" to continue.
```

Any kind of direction to fix this one is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The FETCH only needs the cursor name - the "c" isn't needed.  Try FETCH cur INTO id, scum;

Answer (score 1):

A Simplified version using `IMPLICIT` open and fetch of cursors(parameterised)

```
 DECLARE
  CURSOR cur(v_USER VARCHAR2)
  IS
   SELECT sid, serial# FROM v$session where username = v_USER;
 BEGIN
  FOR I IN cur('ABC')
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(I.sid || ' ' || I.serial#);
  END LOOP;
 END;
```

Answer (score 0):

- In  `FETCH c cur INTO id, s_num;` `c` is redundant, remove it.
- Change the defination of id and s_num as followes:
  `id v$session.sid%type;` 
  `s_num v$session.serial#%type`;
- Add `exit when cur%notfound;` as the exit condition for the loop.

  ```
  DECLARE
  CURSOR cur IS
  SELECT sid, serial# FROM v$session where username = 'ABC';
  id    v$session.sid%type;
  s_num v$session.serial#%type;
  BEGIN
   OPEN cur;
   LOOP
   FETCH cur
    INTO id, s_num;
      exit when cur%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line(id || ' ' || s_num);
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE cur;
  END;
  ```